# Exception in thread "main" io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException How to solve ? Beginner

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, bdd

How to solve this? I'm receiving the following error:

```
Dec 17, 2020 10:56:18 PM cucumber.api.cli.Main run
WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use     io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
Exception in thread "main" io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException:             
Only one plugin can use STDOUT, now both pretty and json use it. If you use more than one plugin you must specify output path with json:DIR|FILE|URL
at io.cucumber.core.plugin.PluginFactory.defaultOutOrFailIfAlreadyUsed(PluginFactory.java:130)
at io.cucumber.core.plugin.PluginFactory.instantiate(PluginFactory.java:75)
at io.cucumber.core.plugin.PluginFactory.create(PluginFactory.java:63)
at io.cucumber.core.plugin.Plugins.createPlugins(Plugins.java:32)
at io.cucumber.core.plugin.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:25)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$Builder.build(Runtime.java:171)
at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:90)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:30)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add some code so that we can have context of what you are doing.